# POI and large Word documents

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, heap-memory

I'm using POI to read Word documents and extract tables. It works fine with smaller documents but give Out of Heap exceptions with larger documents.

Here's the current code:

```
public List<XWPFTable> extractTables() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(source);
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);
        return doc.getTables();
    }
```

It chokes on the getTables() call. I've seen similar posts for excel where they have a read only accessor, but was unable to find something like that for word. I already gave more Heap Space for the application and it works sometimes. I guess depending on the amount of RAM available. I'm trying to prevent it from happening. User's will try a huge document sooner or later.

Any idea on how to prevent this?